# Copy an array from mysql_fetch_array() to another array

Tags: php, mysql

i have a multidimensional array which gets it's data from `mysql_fetch_array()` function. But when i try to copy it into another array, it only copy the first index of the previous array.

here's my code snippet :

```
$old = array();

$sql = "SELECT price, item FROM sale";
$query = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die("sql error : ".mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $old[] = $data;
}

$new = array();
foreach($old as $foo){
$new[] = $foo;
}

print_r($old);
```

will display:

```
Array (
      [0] => Array ( [0] => 1100 [price] => 1100 [1] => 1 [item] => 1 ) 
      [1] => Array ( [0] => 1200 [price] => 1200 [1] => 10 [item] => 10 )
      [2] => Array ( [0] => 300 [price] => 300 [1] => 15 [item] => 15 )
)
```

while

```
print_r($new);
```

only display:

```
Array ([0] => Array ( [0] => 1100 [price] => 1100 [1] => 1 [item] => 1 ))
```

is there another way to copy the entire data of $old array?

Comment: This code is okay. Except using obsolete `mysql` api. As for your question - it is `$new = $old;`

Comment: Use the mysqli api. That way you can get all of the rows at once using **mysqli_fetch_all**

Comment: thank you for you responses..
tried `mysqli` api and $new = $old, it worked